# how to install flask using pip on windows using python 3.7.4 and install pip?

Tags: python, pip

When I did `pip install Flask` I got an error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask
```

What can I do in order install Flask?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.885]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. כל הזכויות שמורות.

C:\Users\מחשב>cd Documents

C:\Users\מחשב\Documents>cd C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton

C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton>mkdir myproject
A subdirectory or file myproject already exists.

C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton>myproject
'myproject' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton>mkdir myproject

C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton>cd myproject

C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton\myproject>python3 -m venv venv
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton\myproject>py -3 -m venv venv

C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton\myproject>venv\Scripts\activate

(venv) C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton\myproject>pip install Flask
Collecting Flask
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping

(venv) C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton\myproject>python -m ensurepip --default-pip
Looking in links: C:\Users\84D7~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpljqyz7od
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\מחשב\documents\pyton\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\מחשב\documents\pyton\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages (19.0.3)

(venv) C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton\myproject>pip -V
pip 19.0.3 from c:\users\מחשב\documents\pyton\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

(venv) C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton\myproject>py -3 -m venv venv

(venv) C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton\myproject>venv\Scripts\activate

(venv) C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton\myproject>pip install Flask
Collecting Flask
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping

(venv) C:\Users\מחשב\Documents\pyton\myproject>
```

Comment: you can use the wheeler file

Comment: pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/93/628509b8d5dc749656a9641f4caf13540e2cdec85276964ff8f43bbb1d3b/Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: which version shuold I dawnload for python 3.7.4.  https://pypi.org/simple/pip/

Comment: what is the binarry file?????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a sentense
 --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org 
this work!!!!!!!
when you have Blocking on the computer You need to remove the security before the library you want

pip install  --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org  Flask

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an SSL certification error when downloading packages from pypi:

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):

Could you try adding pypi as a trusted host and reinstalling? Something along the lines of:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org flask
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: it's doesnot help me the error is still :       Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for flask

Comment: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:

Comment: how did you install python?